# Make an 'if else' statement in bash which toggles key repeat

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sh, xset

```
#!/bin/bash
var1="r on"
var2="r off"
xset=$xset
if [[ $(xset r on) = true ]] then
  $xset "$var1"
 else
  $xset "$var2"
fi
```

is the script which I tried to run to toggle the key repeat.

When running the script, the key repeat is kept on/off.

Apologies in advance if I sound like a newbie. I'm really new to this scripting stuff.

Edit: I tried running the script in a terminal, but the output was:

```
Toggle key repeat.sh: 5: Toggle key repeat.sh: [[: not found
Toggle key repeat.sh: 9: Toggle key repeat.sh: r off: not found
```

Comment: You are missing a semicolon `]]; then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(xset q) =~ 'auto repeat:  on' ]]
then
    xset r off
else
    xset r on
fi
```

Comment: This works, but when running it from the terminal it doesn't work. Still, it suffices.

Comment: how do you run it

Comment: To correct myself, it does work when run from terminal, doing ```./script.sh```

Comment: dont think anything is tracking the repeat setting in the console (believe xset is tracked by x) you can set repeat with setterm --repeat on|off or echo -e "\033[?8h" and "\033[?8l"